# Regex flexible remove dash between characters only

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove the dashes between characters only but the way I'm doing it I need to run two separate `replaceAll` commands - is there a way to do it with just one? It must allow for French characters.

```
.replaceAll("([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])-([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])", "$1 $2")
```

The desired outcome is from this:

```
Pourquoi s'intéresse-t-elle à lui.
Ma chère je comptais là-dessus - figurez-vous.
Il y a 1-2 chemins que nous pouvons choisir.
```

to this:

```
Pourquoi s'intéresse t elle à lui
Ma chère je comptais là dessus - figurez vous.
Il y a 1-2 chemins que nous pouvons choisir.
```

With the above pattern I can only fix the second sentence or with an adjustment, the first sentence but I want to fix them both with one pattern..

Regex to match the first sentence:

https://regex101.com/r/fHQNYP/1

and to match the second sentence:

https://regex101.com/r/j4YGrj/1

Comment: @user7294900 You haven't linked to an answer, just to the whole question. It doesn't look like that would work anyway.

Comment: @Izruo The adjustment would be `([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])-([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])-([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])`. This adjustment makes it work with the first sentence. The original pattern works with the second sentence.

Comment: @Izruo I added the two regex patterns to match each sentence into my question for clarity.

Comment: @Izruo How would your pattern avoid removing the dash in the second sentence that is not surrounded by characters?

Comment: @Hasen I just now spotted (and read from the pattern) that the crucial dashes are in the words `intéresse-t-elle` and `là-dessus`. Before I simply saw one leftover dash with spaces around it and therefore assumed it was what we are looking for. The suggestion I made is therefore wrong and I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @Izruo Yeah it's decent answer and probably is useful for what I need it for. But I just wondered on the off chance there was something like "1-2" the dash would be removed there too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't match hyphens on both ends of a `t` word because the trailing `([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])` in the regex consumes the `t`, and there is no way for the regex to match it again during the next iteration. Have a look:

```
Pourquoi s'intéresse-t-elle à lui.
                    ^^^
                      First match (replace with " t ")

Pourquoi s'intéresse-t-elle à lui.
                       ^
                       +-- search goes on from here, no more matches!
```

**You want to only match hyphens between letters**, so use

```java
.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{L})-(?=\\p{L})", " ")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d8NNLE/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=\p{L})` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with any Unicode letter
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=\p{L})` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with any Unicode letter.

Comment: Wow looks like we might have a winner there. That seems to work even with the new sentence I added into my question.

Comment: @Hasen Lookarounds are zero-width assertions, they match empty strings, and only return true or false, letting the regex engine know whether to go on matching or to fail and backtrack.

Answer (score 0):

That is a tricky one. For one side, you need to specify all the accented characters. You cannot use `\w` because that would only include non-accented. And even though, having patterns like `-t-` implies that the second character has to be declared as zero width.

So, I think this can solve both problems:

```
"Pourquoi s'intéresse-t-elle à lui. Ma chère je comptais là-dessus - figurez-vous."
.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z\\u00C0-\\u017F])-((?=[a-zA-Z\\u00C0-\\u017F]))", "$1 $2");
```

Comment: Please format your code onto separate lines, it's not readable like that.

Answer (score -1):

This is the regular expression to replace all dashes.

```
stringValue.replaceAll("[-]", " ")
```

This is for replacing dashes in between words.

```
stringValue.replaceAll("(\\b-\\b)", " ")
```

This is late but work for the answer:

```
stringValue.replaceAll("(^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ](?<![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])|(?<=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])-(?<![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])|(?<=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])$[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])", " ")
```

Comment: I believe the intention is to specifically replace dashes between 2 characters and not just all dashes

Comment: Please remove your answer, this obviously doesn't answer it at all as dshelya correctly noted.

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: Make a regex showing it removes the dashes in the example sentences.

Comment: It does work with the examples I gave but with my code I was using `[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]` to detect only alpha characters. Can you make your pattern avoid numeric values?

Comment: Try this ((?<![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])|(?<=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])-(?<![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])|(?<=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]))

Comment: @Wing Kui Tsoi Woah that pattern looks insane.

Comment: It's still trying. Please try this updated one: (^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ](?<![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])|(?<=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])-(?<![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])|(?<=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])(?![a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])$[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]) @Hasen

Comment: As I tried, it works for your example.